# Connecting with linux sFTP server using Groovy

Tags: file, permissions, sftp

I am trying to run the following Groovy scripts which intends to alter file permissions to 777 on a linux server -

```
@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader = true)
@Grab(group="com.jcraft", module="jsch", version="0.1.46")
import com.jcraft.jsch.*;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSession;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Vector;    
java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties()

config.put "StrictHostKeyChecking", "no"
JSch ssh = new JSch();
Session session = null;
Session sess = ssh.getSession ("USERNAME", "HOST", 22);
sess.with {
setConfig config
setPassword ("PASSWORD");
connect()
Channel chan = openChannel ("sftp");
chan.connect()
ChannelSftp sftp = (ChannelSftp) chan;

"chmod 777".execute(null, new File("WORKING DIRECTORY\Test_ftpuser_place.txt"))

chan.disconnect()
disconnect()
}
```

---

Furthermore, I tried with the following command instead of Chmod, but still it didn't work.

```
builder = new AntBuilder()
builder.chmod(dir:"WORKING DIRECTORY", perm:'+rwxrwxrwx', includes:'Test_ftpuser.txt')
```

And im getting this error on running the former part of the script -

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "chmod": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

    at java_lang_Runtime$exec$0.call(Unknown Source)

    at ConsoleScript45$_run_closure1.doCall(ConsoleScript45:45)

    at ConsoleScript45.run(ConsoleScript45:18)

Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

    ... 3 more
```

Could someone please help me out with this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this line:

> "chmod 777".execute(null, new File("WORKING DIRECTORY\Test_ftpuser_place.txt"))

The second parameter in the "execute" method represents the current working directory (see the docs [here](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#execute(java.lang.String[],%20java.io.File))). You're using it to represent the file you're looking to change, which I don't think is what it was intended for.

Try creating the file first, and then changing its permissions. You can also use [methods on the File object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) to set these, without having to use "process".execute():

```
def myFile = new File("path/to/file")
myFile.write("Hello World")
myFile.setReadable(true, false)
myFile.setWritable(true, false)
myFile.setExecutable(true, false)
```